# Android: Sherlock action bar drop down

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, actionlistener, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to implement a drop down list as navigation for the action bar in Android.
I can see the drop down list and the items, but I can't get the clicking event.

I'm not sure what I'm missing since I was following the tutorial in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

This is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        OnNavigationListener mOnNavigationListener;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.info_layout);
        // getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
         getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(getSupportActionBar().NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.navigation_array, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        mOnNavigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() {
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
                switch (itemPosition) {
                case 1:
                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ZoekAndBoekActivity.class);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                case 4:
                    break;
                case 5:
                    break;
                }
                // return super.onOptionsItemSelected(itemPosition);
                return true;
            }
        };
        getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, mOnNavigationListener);
    }
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that you don't get click events? You're creating intent but doesn't do anything with it. Try something like this:

```
switch (itemPosition) {
    case 1:
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ZoekAndBoekActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    ...
}
```

or add writing to log to be sure:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
    Log.d("SomeTag", "Get click event at position: " + itemPosition);
    switch (itemPosition) {
        ...
    }
}
```

and see in the logcat output for message with "SomeTag" when you click on items.

Comment: doesn't do anything, doesn't even enter in the onNavigationItemSelected

Comment: @noloman If your solution differs from what was given here, it would be helpful to others if you posted it.

Comment: How can i get item of selected position?

Answer (score -1):

I think the return statement must be false inside the switch case, and your case must have brackets.. Hope it helps :)))

Comment: A case statement does not need brackets and each case needs to return `true`.